# How to count items in a string

Tags: python, count

I am trying to grab fileID, done be grabFile function, and then count sentences, done by sentcount statement. Now I am getting 0 for all sentence count. I just checked back. The problem is that my grabAbs is not grab the abstract for me. Can anyone help me check the code and let me know what is the problem? Thanks.

```
grabFile=re.findall(r'File\s+\:\s+(\w\d{7})',mytext)
if len(grabFile) == 0:
    matchFile= "N/A"
else:
    matchFile = grabFile[0]

newtext=re.sub(r'\n','',mytext)
newtext=re.sub(r'\s+','',newtext)
grabAbs=re.findall(r'Abstract\s+\:(\w.+)',newtext)
if len(grabAbs) == 0:
    matchAbs= "N/A"
else:
    matchAbs = grabAbs

#filesents={}
sentcount=0
for each in matchAbs.split('\.'):
    if each =='N/A':
        sentcount=0
    else:
        sentcount +=1
    print sentcount, matchFile
```

The text from Abstract of one of the files (a95000006):

> Abstract   :
>   9500006  Wang   This award for a Grant Opportunity for Academic Liaison with Industry (GOALI) research project will develop a new methodology for reducing geometric variation in aluminum automotive space frames.'

Comment: How about some example input?

Comment: Do you mean example output? It looks like this: ·0 a95000003         0 a95000006·

Comment: I think he means example **input**.  Values for `newtext`.

Comment: @Q-ximi, No, he means example **input**. Like the content of `mytext`.

Comment: I just updated one of the abstracts in the post. It is expected to be grabbed by `grabAbs`, and then split for later counting.

Answer (score 0):

<del>The regex in this line</del>

`grabAbs=re.findall(r'Abstract\s+\:(\w.+)',newtext)`

<del>assumes that there is always at least one whitespace character between 'Abstract' and the colon ':'

If I was writing an abstract, I would put _Abstract: text of my abstract_ with the colon right after the word Abstract. If you change the `\s+` to `\s*` you will allow for the case that there is no space before the colon. Try that and see if it solves your problem.

--EDIT--

after seeing your sample input, the problem is more likely that there is a line break right after the colon, and you have not set the multiline search flag on your regex. Try this:</del>

```
grabAbs=re.findall(r'Abstract\s+\:(\w.+)',newtext, flags=re.M)
```

--EDIT--

@jammon pointed out that the line above the one I mentioned removes all spaces. Therefore the space before the colon **will be removed**. Also, the line above that removes all newline characters. Since the newline character after the colon is being removed, the `\w` in the capture group can't match. Perhaps the capture group should just be `(.+)` like so:

```
grabAbs=re.findall(r'Abstract\:(.+)',newtext)
```

Comment: The line before that deletes all spaces, so this line should never match.

Comment: There was a line breaker after `abstract   :`, but I sub it with a whitespace. Not sure why it's still not working. The 'flags-re.M' does not help either, still printing out all 'N/A'.

Comment: Oh! in that case, since you stripped the newlines, doesn't the `\w` never match now? How about just having the capture group be `(.+)` instead of `(\w.+)`

Comment: and btw, do you really want to be deleting all spaces? won't that make the abstract illegible?